# What are some sites that offer decent deals on college textbooks?

Tags: cost-cutting, college

Textbooks are quite expensive these days. I know of [half.com](http://www.half.ebay.com/), but I don't know of anything else.

Comment: I suggest you reword this question and make it a Community Wiki.  I would ask: `What are some sites which offer deals on college textbooks?`  The Community Wiki (CW) is more appropriate for these types of questions which can not actually be answered objectively.  See this about off-topic questions http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-topics-are-not-allowed-on-money  And this example of a CW: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/what-are-some-products-that-youre-better-on-not-going-cheap-on/2731#2731

Comment: @George you're correct, so I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried seeing if your college's bookstore offers used textbooks?  [Half.com](http://half.com) still may be cheaper, but used from your bookstore beats new by a lot.

Also, from [this website](http://www.cheapism.com/) which I just discovered comes a [list of places](http://www.cheapism.com/cheap-textbooks) to rent textbooks or buy them at a discount.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon got into this market](http://www.amazon.com/New-Used-Textbooks-Books/b?ie=UTF8&node=465600) a few years ago and given their customer service reputation, I'd say it's a good place to check out.

Comment: I second that. Some times buying used books takes more effort than its worth. Amazon has a great pro/con ratio to make it profitable.